# Azure Python Sdk list all web apps in Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-python-sdk

I dot apologise for the basic question but I am having hard time to find the documentation to solve the issue.

I am looking for the azure python sdk for the webapps to be able to get a list of all the webapps in a given subscription.

Using az cli I can just run the command `az webapp list` and I am able to retrieve the entire list of web apps in my subscription. There is any equivalent python sdk to achieve the same output?

Please if my question is not clear, just let me know and I can explain better.

Thank you so much for any help you can provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/app-service?view=azure-python

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-web-python-manage

This second link is at the bottom of the official doc page, I hope this helps.